# my struggle with python mock

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking

I am learning to mock in python but I am not even able to get the basic mocking working. Please give your suggestion to fix the below code snippet..

```
from mock import patch

def dec_print(msg)
    print("+++ " + msg)

@patch("print", dec_print)
def fun():
    print("Hello");


fun()
```

Thanks
Jude

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What are you trying to mock? Can you clarify a little bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocking builtins like `print` is a little tricky. First, you need to know that they are stored in a special `__builtins__` module:

```
>>> __builtins__.print("hello world")
hello world
```

So, you need to patch that `__builtins__` module. I first tried these:

```
@patch("__builtins__.print", dec_print)
#and
@patch("__builtin__.print", dec_print)
```

But these both gave an `ImportError`.

Next, I tried `mock.patch` instead of just `mock`, which lets you specify the object you want to patch (instead of using the string to import the object):

```
@patch.object(__builtins__, "print", dec_print)
```

This works, but then since you're calling `print` inside of `dec_print`, you get a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error.

So, to fix that you can replace `print` with `sys.stdout.write`. Here is the final working code for mocking `print`:

```
import sys

from mock import patch

def dec_print(msg):
    sys.stdout.write("+++ {}\n".format(msg))

@patch.object(__builtins__, "print", dec_print)
def fun():
    print("Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun()
```

Output:

```
$ python x.py
+++ Hello
```

**Edit**: in response to the new information you posted (it printed the message twice, once with the mock and once without):

You're seeing it printed twice because you put `fun()` at the top level of the module, so it runs when `@patch` imports `tstmock`, then it runs again normally. You should wrap this call in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)).

```
...original code...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the input, I managed to get to working by changing the code as below.

```
from mock import patch

def log(msg):
    print(msg)

def dec_print(msg):
    print("+++ " + msg)

@patch("tstmock.log", dec_print)
def fun():
    log("Hello")

fun()
```

However, even after I patched the function log, it is getting called and generating below output

```
+++ Hello
Hello
```

Comment: No problem! 1. You should edit your original question with this information. The answers section here is just for answers. 2. You're seeing it printed twice because you put `fun()` at the top level of the module, so it runs when `@patch` imports `tstmock`, then it runs again normally. You should wrap this call in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do I updated my answer with this information as well.